# Object Reference not set to an instance Exception

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have a `DataGridView` which is bound to a datasource. I have also a `TextBox` to filter the records. In `TextChanged` event of the textbox I have a this line of code: i bind the gridview through designview of the form drag the gridview and choose datasource ... and then the member table.

```
(gvSideMember.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = 
    string.Format("F_NAME LIKE '%{0}%'", textSearch.Text);
```

But when I try to filter records it shows me that object reference is not set to an instance. The datasource has records. I don't know what's going on, kindly guide me, help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is `textSearch` null?

Comment: no that is not nul during debug it shows value

Comment: If `DataSource` is not a `DataTable`, then `(DataSource as DataTable)` returns `null`.

Comment: yes it is the reason how to create the datasource as table i simply bind it through design not programingly

Comment: Never use the `as` keyword if you are not prepared to accept that the result might be `null`! If you say `(source as Table).View` you are not accepting that the `as` operator might give `null`. In that case you should use cast syntax, `((Table)source).View`, instead. When the former fails, you get an non-informative exception message _Object reference not set to an instance_. But with the latter, you get something like _Unable to cast object of type 'INTERESTING_INFO' to type 'Table'_, and that helps you understand what you do. So in short: Avoid `as` in such cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `as` keyword. Could it be that `gvSideMember.DataSource`, although having records, is not of the type DataTable, so that `(gvSideMember.DataSource as DataTable)` is `null`?

Comment: i think datasource is not a table it is through the dataset

Answer (score 1):

If `DataSource` is not a `DataTable`, then `(DataSource as DataTable)` returns `null`.

What you can do, for instance, is this:

```
var src = gvSideMember.DataSource;
```

Put a breakpoint AFTER that line, then when you hit it, QuickWatch `src` in Visual Studio to see its type and contents.

Then you can update your source code to use the proper type of `DataSource`.

**EDIT** If the DataSource is a DataSet, it will contain one or more tables. If it contains a single table, that is easy to retrieve:

```
var src = (DataSet) gvSideMember.DataSource;
var table = src.Tables[0];
```

But if it contains more tables, you can retrieve it with the right number (0, 1, ...) or the name:

```
var table = src.Tables["MyTable"];
```

Comment: Avoid `as` when you require the cast to succeed. Then you will see the actual type already in the exception text, and you won't have to debug to find that type.

Answer (score 0):

You can test nullity before the statement - in the example below I'm just logging that they are null, so you'll still get the error, but you can use these checks to either decide not to perform the operation or supply defaults etc.

```
if (gvSideMember == null) {
    Debug.WriteLine("gvSideMember is null");
}

if (textSearch == null) {
    Debug.WriteLine("textSearch is null");
}

(gvSideMember.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = 
    string.Format("F_NAME LIKE '%{0}%'", textSearch.Text);
```

You can test anything that *could* possibly be null - even `(gvSideMember.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView` if you like.